# Draw a triangle using © symbols

Tags: c#, for-loop

Take a look at this problem: *Write a program that prints a triangle of 9 copyright symbols `©`*

The console should print a simple triangle using those `©`symbols. The triangle has to be empty, not filled with `©` thingies.

I changed the console character encoding:

```
 Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

so `©` prints correctly. I also changed the font.

I've been trying to figure out a way to draw the triangle by using a *for loop*, but my rookie's knowledge is obviously still too insufficient for this kind of tasks.

Could you give me some tips/hints as to how to draw the triangle with a *for loop*?

By the way, I found the problem solved like this:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        char copyRight = '\u00A9';
        Console.WriteLine("{0,4}\n{0,3}{0,2}\n{0,2}{0,4}\n{0}{0,2}{0,2}{0,2}", copyRight);
```

Answer (score 10):

> Could you give me some tips/hints as to how to draw the triangle with a for loop?

Sure.  Start with: can you write a program *that you understand* that draws a triangle without using any loops?

Once you've done that, can you write that program using a simpler loop, like a `while`?

If not, learn how `while` works before tackling `for`.  You should be able to clearly answer the question "precisely what is the difference between code in the form `if(condition) statement` and `while(condition) statement`?"

Once you've done that, can you transform your correct program written using `while` into an equivalent program that uses `for`?  There is a very clear relationship between `while` and `for`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a plain example. It looks scarier than it is.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Draw(' ', '\u00A9', 20, true);
}

static void Draw(char sym, char back, int length, bool padding)
{
    if (length < 5)
    {
        length = 5;
    }
    else if ((length % 2) == 0) // Ensure an odd length using a modulo operation
    {
        length++;
    }

    if (padding)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(back, length));
    }

    int mid = length / 2;
    int left = mid;
    int right = mid + 1;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(new string(back, left));
        Console.Write(new string(sym, right - left));
        Console.Write(new string(back, length - right));
        Console.WriteLine();

        left--;
        right++;
    }
    while (left != 0);

    if (padding)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(back, length));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
©©©©©©©©©
©©©© ©©©©
©©©   ©©©
©©     ©©
©       ©
©©©©©©©©©
```

Alternative version for 9 symbols:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Render(Draw('\u00A9', 4));
    Render(Draw('\u00A9', 8));
    Render(Draw('\u00A9', 16));
}

static char[,] Draw(char sym, int height)
{
    int width = (height * 2) - 1;
    char[,] map = new char[height, width];
    int x = width - 1;
    int y = height - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        map[y, i * 2] = sym;

        if (i != 0)
        {
            map[y - i, i] = sym;
            map[y - i, x - i] = sym;
        }
    }

    return map;
}

static void Render(char[,] map)
{
    int width = map.GetLength(1);
    int height = map.GetLength(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            char c = map[i, j];

            Console.Write(c == '\0' ? ' ' : c);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
   ©
  © ©
 ©   ©
© © © ©
       ©
      © ©
     ©   ©
    ©     ©
   ©       ©
  ©         ©
 ©           ©
© © © © © © © ©
               ©
              © ©
             ©   ©
            ©     ©
           ©       ©
          ©         ©
         ©           ©
        ©             ©
       ©               ©
      ©                 ©
     ©                   ©
    ©                     ©
   ©                       ©
  ©                         ©
 ©                           ©
© © © © © © © © © © © © © © © ©
```

Comment: How long it took you to come up with the solution?!, I was asked this question during an interview, except I was asked to draw a different height triangle every second for 10 seconds...so on the first second it will be one'*' then ** ....etc until I reach  Render(Draw('\u00A9', 16));....the interviewer left and told me I have an hour to solve this...needless to say I spent 15 minutes to get the timer event correct ( :) ) haven't used a time object before, anyway.... I couldn't solve the problem in an hour which made me feel stupid! :(... how long it took you to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've always wondered nobody used [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void DrawEmptyTriangle( char symbol, char padSymbol, int triangleBase)
{
    // heuristics - this is because of the 2nd line
    int alignment = triangleBase - 3;
    int half = triangleBase / 2 + 1;

    // top and bottom line are different from the others,
    // so it is easier to generate them separately
    string top = symbol.ToString ( ).PadLeft ( half, padSymbol).PadRight ( triangleBase, padSymbol);
    // if this is new to you - Enumerable.Repeat will generate a sequence of n character elements
    // string.Join will make a string inserting, in this case, a space between them
    string bottom = string.Join ( " ", Enumerable.Repeat ( 'x', half ) );

    Console.WriteLine ( top );
    for ( int index = 1; index < triangleBase; index+=2 )
    {
        string line =
            string.Format ( "{0}{1}{0}", symbol, new string ( padSymbol, index ) )
            .PadLeft ( alignment, padSymbol )
            .PadRight ( alignment, padSymbol );
        alignment++;
        Console.WriteLine ( line );
    }
    Console.WriteLine ( bottom );
}
```

Read the comments in the code, and play a little with this method :)